# How to zip Mac app that preserve all the properties

Tags: java, macos, ant, zip

I have created one app at Mac using JavaFX. I am using ant to build and zip that app into a folder.

On trying zipping using

```
<zip destfile="MyApp.zip" basedir="MyApp"/>
```

It creating zip file but not preserving Properties of JavaAppLauncher which is found at MyApp/Contents.MacOS/

Then I have tried this command -

```
<exec executable="zip" dir="${basedir}/target">
  <arg value="-r" />
  <arg value="My-app.zip" />
  <arg value="My.app" />
</exec>
```

On unzipping this zip I found that this app also not launching. Now JavaAppLauncher's property is preserved, but this time I am facing issue of not preserving properties of **libjli.dylib** (which is an alias) found at MyApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/MacOS, zip converting it to Dynamic Library.

Might be there are some more files which are failed to preserve their properties on zip. So how to preserve all the properties of libs, unix files, alias etc added inside app, so that I can successfully launch it after unzipping.

Thanks

Comment: I think most developers use diskimages to solve this, not that it can't be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my system at least, `libjli.dylib` is a Unix-style symbolic link rather than a Mac "alias", in which case you should be able to add the `-y` option to the `zip` command to preserve symlinks

```
<exec executable="zip" dir="${basedir}/target">
  <arg value="-r" />
  <arg value="-y" />
  <arg value="My-app.zip" />
  <arg value="My.app" />
</exec>
```

If it is an alias in the mac sense rather than a symlink then you could try using [`ditto`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ditto.1.html), which can build zips that preserve the resource forks and hfs metadata in the same `__MACOSX` form that Finder's "create archive" option uses. In order to extract such a zip correctly users must double click it in the Finder (or extract it with ditto) rather than using `unzip`.

```
<exec executable="ditto" dir="${basedir}/target">
  <arg value="-c" />
  <arg value="-k" />
  <arg value="--keepParent" />
  <arg value="--sequesterRsrc" />
  <arg value="My.app" />
  <arg value="My-app.zip" />
</exec>
```

Or, as demure suggests in the comments, create a compressed disk image instead, which is the normal way Mac users expect their apps to be distributed

```
<exec executable="hdiutil">
  <arg value="create" />
  <arg value="-srcfolder" />
  <arg file="${basedir}/target" />
  <arg value="-volname" />
  <arg value="My App" />
  <arg file="MyApp.dmg" />
</exec>
```

This will pack the whole contents of `target` into the image, so you may need to change some of your paths a bit so that `My.app` is the only thing in the `srcfolder` (e.g. create it at `target/appbundle/My.app` and then pass `target/appbundle` as the `-srcfolder` to `hdiutil`).

Comment: Thanks for reply, as I have told we are deploying our application using JavaFX so it default creates app and dmg for my app (sorry I forgot to mention about dmg), so we don't need to create dmg for it. We need to zip app only. As per you suggestion I have tried using -y option but it do not preserving the property of libjli.dylib (its kind is as Alias before zip), converting it into Dynamic Library.

Comment: @NeelamSharma I'm not clear as to why you need _both_ a dmg _and_ a zip of the app, but I've added another possibility using the "ditto" tool.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have tried with <arg value="-y" /> that worked fine for me :) Earlier I was trying by copying app at root that was not working. Thanks a ton :)